# After deployment at OpenShift, opening JSF page ends up in "The XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it" error

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jboss, openshift

I made basic web service with two pages. I used primefaces lib and jsf. On my locallhost (jboss 6.x) the webpage works correctly. If I deployed it to openshift It looks like on the screenshot:
[image]

Here is my pom.xml:
``

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
       http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
                 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
<artifactId>aj</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>aj</name>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>prime-repo</id>
        <name>PrimeFaces Maven Repository</name>
        <url>http://repository.primefaces.org</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
    <repository>
  <id>central</id>
  <name>Maven Repository Switchboard</name>
  <layout>default</layout>
  <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
  <snapshots>
    <enabled>false</enabled>
  </snapshots>
</repository>
</repositories>

<properties>
    <!-- Explicitly declaring the source encoding eliminates the following message: -->
    <!-- [WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent! -->
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <!-- Define the version of JBoss' Java EE 6 APIs and Tools we want to import. -->
    <javaee6.with.tools.version>1.0.0.M1</javaee6.with.tools.version>
    <!-- Alternatively, comment out the above line, and un-comment the line below to use version 3.0.0.Beta1-redhat-1 
        which is a release certified to work with JBoss EAP 6. It requires you have access to the JBoss EAP 6 maven repository. -->
    <!-- <javaee6.spec.version>3.0.0.Beta1-redhat-1</javaee6.spec.version> -->
</properties>
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- JBoss distributes a complete set of Java EE 6 APIs including a Bill of Materials (BOM). A BOM specifies 
            the versions of a "stack" (or a collection) of artifacts. We use this here so that we always get the correct versions of 
            artifacts. Here we use the jboss-javaee-6.0-with tools stack (you can read this as the JBoss stack of the Java EE 6 APIs, 
            with some extras tools for your project, such as Arquillian for testing) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.bom</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-javaee-6.0-with-tools</artifactId>
            <version>${javaee6.with.tools.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
<dependencies>
<dependency>
<groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
<artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
        <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
<artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
<version>3.5</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>javax</groupId>
<artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
<version>6.0</version>
<scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
<plugins>
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
                <compilerArguments>
                    <endorseddirs>${basedir}</endorseddirs>
                </compilerArguments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${basedir}</outputDirectory>
                        <silent>true</silent>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                <version>6.0</version>
                                <type>jar</type>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>


</build>

</project>
```

Has anyone got the same problem? Thanks a lot for help.
web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
</context-param>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>faces/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

index.xhtml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head>
    <title>Facelet Title</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
        <p:layout fullPage="true">
            <p:layoutUnit position="north" size="100" resizable="true" closable="true" collapsible="true">
                Header
            </p:layoutUnit>
            <p:layoutUnit position="south" size="100" closable="true" collapsible="true">
                Footer
            </p:layoutUnit>
            <p:layoutUnit position="west" size="250"  collapsible="true">
                <h:form>
                    <p:menu>
                        <p:submenu >
                            <p:menuitem value="home"  action="#{menuBean.home()}" />
                            <p:menuitem value="wynik"  action="#{menuBean.wynik()}" />
                        </p:submenu>
                    </p:menu>
                </h:form>
            </p:layoutUnit>
            <p:layoutUnit position="center">
                Welcome to PrimeFaces
            </p:layoutUnit>
        </p:layout>
        <br />
        <h:link outcome="welcomePrimefaces" value="Primefaces welcome page" />
        <br />
        <h:link outcome="welcomePrimefaces" value="Primefaces welcome page" />
    </h:body>
</html>
```

Comment: Show us your index.xhtml and web.xml

Comment: In simple terms, change the URL pattern of `Faces Servlet` from `/faces/*` to `*.xhtml`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're attempting to access the index.xhtml.  However, your faces servlet mapping indicates that it should be /context-root/faces/index.xhtml

Also note that open shift is based on JBoss AS 7, not JBoss AS 6.  If you want to verify that your application will work locally you should switch to AS7.